# double calling API with async function within useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My API is getting called twice after reloading the page when I look into the console
(the first two and the last two are different API calls)
[image: some messages rendered]
I set my dataFetched initial value to **false**.

What's the reason why API is getting called twice?

I only want to call it once.

Here is the code snippet.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const response = await fetch(
                "https://opentdb.com/api.phpamount=5&category=31&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
            );
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            setData(jsonData.results);
        }

        if (!dataFetched) {
            fetchData();
            setDataFetched(true);
        }
    }, [dataFetched]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the useEffect function is meant to be fired based on the changes you make to the state variable dataFetched, it is getting fired for the 2nd time when you change it from false->true. I have modified your code by taking out the listener for the state variable dataFetched as below so that it won't get fired for the 2nd time.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
   async function fetchData(){
      const response = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.phpamount=5&category=31&difficulty=easy&type=multiple')
      const jsonData = await response.json() 
      setData(jsonData.results)
   }

   if (!dataFetched) {
      fetchData();
      setDataFetched(true);
   } 
})
```